# .gas(gas_limit)(target_account_address) 0xProtocol Solidity Syntax

Tags: solidity

Hi I got this code from 0xProject Exchange.sol

https://0xproject.com/wiki#Deployed-Addresses:

Quote: "TokenContract(contract_address).balanceOf.gas(gas_limit)(target_account_address); // Limit gas to prevent reentrancy"

Could you explain what syntax this is:
".gas(gas_limit)(target_account_address)" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means

```
TokenContract(contract_address).balanceOf(target_account_address);
```

But the address that is calling this line will get gas limit by inserting 
.gas(gas_limit) after balanceOf

because The called token contract may attempt to change state, but will not be able to due to an added gas limit.